# External window is empty with "tk.Toplevel" and "parent"

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

When I click on a label to open an external window (**tertiary**.py), the window opens normally but is empty inside. I don't get errors, but I don't see Tkinter widgets and miscellaneous items.

This is the **secondary** window where there is the label on which I click in order to open an external window. I add, for information purposes only, that this window is called **secondary** because it is displayed in a frame (with a vertical menu on the left) where the **main** window is called `home = tk.Tk()`. The **secondary** window opens and displays correctly in the frame.

Inside the **secondary** window there is the label thanks to which I want to open an external window (not in the frame) called **tertiary**

How can I solve?

**secondary.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

import other_options
from other_options import form_other_options

class Page2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)

        self.configure(bg='white')
        bar1=Frame(self, width=2200, height=35, background="#960000", highlightbackground="#b40909", highlightthickness=0) #grigio chiaro #b40909
        bar1.place(x=0, y=0)

        other_options = Label(self, text="Other Options", bg="#960000", foreground='white', font='Ubuntu 10')
        other_options.place(x=1025, y=7)
        other_options.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: other_options.form_other_options(self))
```

**tertiary.py**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

def form_other_options(parent):

    other_options = tk.Toplevel(parent)
    other_options.title("Other options")
    other_options.geometry("1000x800")
    other_options.config(bg="white")
    other_options.state("normal")

    other_options.transient(parent)


    class checkbox():
        def __init__(self, master, **kw):
            super().__init__(master, **kw)

            labelframe1 = LabelFrame(self, text="checkbox", width=600,height=190, bg="white", foreground='#e10a0a')
            labelframe1.place(x=10, y=13)

            Checkbutton1 = IntVar()

            Button1 = Checkbutton(self, text = "option1",
                    variable = Checkbutton1,
                    onvalue = 1,
                    offvalue = 0,
                    height = 2,
                    width = 10)

            Button1.pack()

    other_options.mainloop()
```

Comment: The `form_other_options()` function in **tertiary.py** doesn't create any Tkinter widgets, which is why you don't see any (i.e. all that it does do is create an empty `Toplevel` window).

Comment: If you [edit] your question and provide a [mre], folks will be more likely to show you how to fix things.

Comment: If you want widgets to appear in a `Toplevel`, the widgets need to be descendants of that window.

Comment: @BryanOakley Can you show me how please?

Comment: @NathanMüller: `new_label = Label(other_options, ...)`

Comment: @BryanOakley So do I have to replace the various "self" with "other_options"? Is the solution simply this or is there a need to make other changes? Thank you

Comment: The first positional parameter must be a widget that is the parent of the new widget. So any widgets you create for the new window must use `other_options` as the first parameter, or the name of some other widget that is a descendant of `other_options`. This is a fundamental part of tkinter. You definitely can't use `self`, since `self` isn't a widget.

Comment: Merely changing `self` to `other_options` as @Bryan suggests is not enough to make things work because there's (at least) one other issue: you never create an *instance* of the nested `checkbox` class (at least in the code currently in your question). Note that just defining a class does not create an instance of it.

Comment: @martineau I see. Can you show me how to do it? I will vote and accept the answer of the first who will help me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The first reason why the window is empty is that you never create an instance of the class `checkbox`, so the code that creates the widgets never runs.

So, the first step is to make sure you create an instance of that class:

```
other_options = tk.Toplevel(parent)
...
cb = checkbox(other_options)
```

When you do that, you will discover other bugs in your code. The first positional argument when creating a tkinter widget must be another widget. If you want the widget to be inside a `Toplevel`, the parent needs to be the toplevel or a descendant. You're using `self` which isn't a widget at all.

A simple fix is to use `master` instead of `self`, since you're passing the toplevel window as the `master` parameter:

```
labelframe1 = LabelFrame(master, ...)
Button1 = Checkbutton(master, ...)
```

You also need to remove the call to `other_options.mainloop()`. Unless there is a very compelling reason to do otherwise, an entire application should only call `mainloop()` exactly once.

---

There are other problems in the code that, strictly speaking, aren't related to the question being asked. For example, you're importing tkinter twice: once as `import tkinter as tk` and once as `from tkinter import *`. You only need to import tkinter once, and [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends to use the first form:

```
import tkinter as tk
```

You'll need to add the prefix `tk.` to every place where you call a tkinter function. This will help make your code easier to understand and helps prevent pollution of the global namespace.

You also should use [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) naming standards. Specifically, class names should begin with an uppercase character. This will also make your code easier to understand.

There's also no reason why your `checkbox` class should be indented. You should move it out of the function.

Also, instead of `checkbox` not inheriting from anything, and then creating a `LabelFrame`, you should just inherit from `LabelFrame`. That way you can use your class more like a real widget, and would enable you to use `self` rather than `master` when creating the other widgets.

```
class Checkbox(tk.LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)
        ...
        button1 = tk.Checkbutton(self, ...)
        ...
```

There are probably other problems, but those are the most obvious.

Comment: @martineau  No, it's not all in vain. She helped me and I will vote and accept her kind response. You could have avoided this comment

Comment: @Bryan Oakley Thank you. I appreciate your kindness in explaining these problems to me. Your question was very helpful to me, so I voted, but I haven't solved the problem yet. Could you copy and paste my code and apply your suggestions to it please? So show me the full code with your kind suggestions? I have tried, but there is something that I will surely have wrong. I would really appreciate the gesture, so I can accept your resolution and set it as a solution. Thank you